# Is it possible to connect a tcp server to a udp client in winsock

Tags: c, tcp, udp, winsock, winsock2

I was doing a simple server client console chat box in winsock2.Then my colleague asked me if i can do a single server multi client connection in which the SERVER will be in TCP and the CLIENTS will be in UDP. Also the client does not know the IP of the server but knows the port number i.e the Client has to search for the server and then connect it.All this over a LAN.

Could any one tell me how to do such program or if possible could post a code for reference.

Comment: Sorry sir you miss understood me. I asked people to post a reference code  with which i can learn with a practical example. That's it. Its like i asked a tutorial with example. Because no winsock tutorial in google covered this topic not even a bit.I asked people to teach me , not to do my job for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TCP and UDP are 2 completely separated worlds.
No, you can't have a TCP server communicating with UDP clients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was naive of me to ask a silly question. But i got the point. I will try the concept with MDNS perspective.

Comment: I do not think this was a silly question. It took me some digging to find this statement "UDP address space, the space of UDP port numbers (in ISO terminology, the TSAPs), is completely disjoint from that of TCP ports." [buried in the BSD sockets documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#gethostbyname_and_gethostbyaddr).  This sort of answers your question in a round-about way.